# How to get Multiple value of actionListener of one frame to another farme in java?

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, actionlistener

I want a value of String name ,father name etc from actionListener of one frame to another frame so that i can make pdf of output values. so how can i do that?

i tried by inheritance & polymorphism method but did'nt get any of resulted outpot.

Comment: Check out ParamDialog (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/dialogs/ParamDialog.java)